# How do I run the constructor code of another .as file from the main.as class file attached to the .fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a main class file called 'Main' which is linked to the main .fla file. Here is the code currently in this file:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import CharacterPkg.Character;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public function Main() {

        var newCharacter:Character = new Character;
        Character();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have a file which I want to use to create a character on the main stage in the .fla file. Here is the code for that file:

```
package  CharacterPkg{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Character extends MovieClip {

    public function Character() {

        trace("This is running");
    }
  }
}
```

I want the constructor code which is in the Character.as file to run when I run the .swf. But I just get a 1136 Error: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1.

I'm at wits ends and have spent two days trying to figure this out. I'm fairly new to this and probably just making some stupid error but I can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with the **Character();** line. There are two things you can do with the class constructor: 1) Instantiate it like **new Character;** 2) Typecast an object like **Character(some_character_instance);** So your line is of type 2, but you don't provide an argument, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import CharacterPkg.Character;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Main() 
        {
            //Character(); //is not needed (won't work).

            var newCharacter :Character = new Character();
            addChild( newCharacter ); //this way auto-runs the constructor function code.
            //newCharacter.someFunction(); //example to run any other functions within newCharacter class.
        }

    }
}
```

When you `addChild` a class, you automatically run the constructor function of that specific class.

To run any other functions within that other class, just use path like `instanceName.xxx();` where your *instanceName* is `newCharacter` and `xxx` represents a function name, close it with a `();`

**Edit**:

To solve second issue, make sure:

1) You have linked `Main.as` to the FLA properly.

- deselect any item(s) by clicking an empty part of Stage, then press **ctrl+F3**
- Is `Main.as` listed as Class (under the "**Publish**" tab)?

2) Code for `Main.as` :

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import CharacterPkg.Character;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var newCharacter :Character;

        public function Main() 
        {
            newCharacter = new Character();
            addChild( newCharacter ); //this way auto-runs the constructor function...
            newCharacter.secondFunction(); //example to run any other functions in newCharacter class..
            newCharacter.thirdFunction(); //another test
        }

    }
}
```

3) Code for `Character.as` (inside a folder named ***CharacterPkg***) :

```
package  CharacterPkg
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Character extends MovieClip 
{

    public function Character() //constructor function 
    {
        trace("This is running");
    }

    public function secondFunction() :void
    {
        trace("This is second Function");
    }

    public function thirdFunction() :void
    {
        trace("This is third Function");
    }

} //end class
}//end package
```

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for your help, the advice you provided worked and allowed me to place a movieclip on the stage without any errors but now there are two slight issues. When I compile, the trace function doesn't work from the constructor, it simply places a movieclip on the screen. Secondly, I made a second function called secondFunction() in the Character.as file and it just has a simple trace command. When I try to call this function from the main.as file it says it's not a function?

Comment: If this worked for your posted Question then mark as correct by clicking the tick`✓` icon. About your second issue, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue (it works fine for me to get a trace from `secondFunction()` code).